# How to put Ruby dependencies in local project folder

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way to put a ruby gem dependencies inside the project root folder ( in vendor directory or something similar ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Run [bundle package](http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html) to cache gems to `./vendor/cache`. As the docs point out, bundler will still look for platform-specific gems on rubygems.org. If you have control over the platforms (e.g. same development and deployment platforms), then you can use [bundle install --local](http://bundler.io/bundle_install.html) in addition to `bundle package`. You may also want to consider a command like `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just generate [gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile) with proper app dependencies, place it into the root of your app, and use [bunlder](/questions/tagged/bunlder) to keep depencencies up-to-date. Since by default all gem will be placed into system folders, I strongly recommend you to use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) or [rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv) utilities to use for purpose of gem keeping.